# Bibtex does not print annote field of misc type

Tags: bibtex

Given this `misc` entry

```
@misc{TheWhiteHouse.2011,
 author = {Obama, Barack},
 year = {2011},
 title = {{Blueprint for a Secure Energy Future}},
 howpublished = {\url{obamawhitehouse.archives.gov/issues/blueprint-secure-energy-future}},
 annote = {{The White House}}
}
```

`Bibtex` does not print the `annote` field. I am using `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}`. The output for me is:

[image]

The source is kind of an internet document, but I want to show its relation to the White House. Any ideas why this does not work or alternatively tips on how to cite this with `Bibtex`? I am too lazy to get myself into `Biblatex` at the end of my Master's thesis.

[Link to Bibtex homepage, misc fields documentation](https://www.bibtex.com/t/template-misc/)

Comment: Note that the supported fields depend on the style being used. I did a search, it is not many that support a `annote` field. Note that the `note` field is supported by all.

Comment: `unsrt` is as basic as it gets, though? How can I fix it?

Comment: If yuo need the `annote` field then you need to find a style that does support it or perhaps switch to `biblatex` (if they support it, I haven't checked)

Comment: Apparently I must finally switch to `Biblatex` indeed. It's weird that the most basic `Bibtex` styles dont support the native bibtex entries fully (all fields).

Comment: From where do you have that `annote` should be a native bibtex field? TeXlive contains 417 bst files, 57 of these know `annote` and they all belong to like 12 families of styles. Notably the standard `natbib` styles are not among these families, neither are the standard bst styles like `unsrt`.

Comment: I don't know who runs `bibtex.com` but I'd take such information with a grain of salt. My editor (emacs) lists `annote` as an optional field when I add a new item, to a `.bib` file telling the user that this might not be supported by the style in use.

Comment: @daleif Thanks, it did not occur to me that `bibtex.com` might not be official.